# verticalAlign sub/sup not Working

Tags: javascript, css

I have two buttons, one which sets the `verticalAlign` property to `sub` and one which sets in to `sub` however, both set it to `sub`.
Below is the code for both:

Superscript

```
document.getElementById("hidden").innerHTML=document.getElementById("text").value;
document.getElementById("hidden").style.verticalAlign="super";
document.getElementById("hidden").style.fontSize="75%";
```

Subscript

```
document.getElementById("hidden").innerHTML=document.getElementById("text").value;
document.getElementById("hidden").style.verticalAlign="sub";
document.getElementById("hidden").style.fontSize="75%";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you controlled the css in the Developer Tool of the browser?
Are the styles shown there?

Otherwise i recommended this method:

```
document.getElementById("hidden").css("vertical-align","super");
document.getElementById("hidden").css("font-size","75%);
```

and

```
document.getElementById("hidden").css("vertical-align","sub");
document.getElementById("hidden").css("font-size","75%);
```

Comment: Excuse me if I'm wrong, but I don't recall '.css' being JS method, but a jQuery one.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. You are right. I've also had the same problem as you, but with '.css' it always work.